# In PyParsing, how to stop a Regex from consuming the entire string

Tags: python, regex, pyparsing

I'm trying to write a function `parse` such that, for example,

```
assert parse("file://foo:bar.txt:r+") == ("foo:bar.txt", "r+")
```

The string consists of a fixed prefix `file://`, followed by a file name (which can consist of one or more of any character), followed by a colon and a string representing access flags.

Here is one implementation using regular expressions:

```
import re

def parse(string):
    SCHEME = r"file://"                             # File prefix
    PATH_PATTERN = r"(?P<path>.+)"                  # One or more of any character
    FLAGS_PATTERN = r"(?P<flags>[rwab+0-9]+)"       # The letters r, w, a, b, a '+' symbol, or any digit

    FILE_RESOURCE_PATTERN = SCHEME + PATH_PATTERN + r":" + FLAGS_PATTERN + r"$"     # The full pattern including the end of line character

    tokens = re.match(FILE_RESOURCE_PATTERN, string).groupdict()
    return tokens['path'], tokens['flags']
```

I would prefer to use [PyParsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/Documentation), however, because it typically gives more detailed error messages if the string doesn't match the expression (rather than `re.match` which simply returns `None`), and I would eventually like to make the `flags` optional.

Following Paul McGuire's answer in [python regex in pyparsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116336/python-regex-in-pyparsing), I made the following attempt:

```
from pyparsing import Word, alphas, nums, StringEnd, Regex, FollowedBy, Suppress, Literal

def parse(string):
    scheme = Literal("file://")
    path = Regex(".+")
    flags = Word(alphas + nums + "+")

    expression = Suppress(scheme) + (~(Suppress(":") + flags + StringEnd()) + path("path") + Suppress(":") + flags("flags") + StringEnd())

    tokens = expression.parseString(string)
    return tokens['path'], tokens['flags']
```

In the second part of the expression, I'm basically trying the negative lookahead `(~suffix + path + suffix)`, where `suffix` is `":" + flags + StringEnd()`. However, when trying to parse `"file://foo:bar.txt:r+"`, I run into the following error:

```
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected ":" (at char 21), (line:1, col:22)
```

Since the string is 21 characters long, I interpret this as that the `Regex` has 'consumed' the entire string so that the suffix is no longer 'found'.

How can I fix the `parse` method using `pyparsing`?

Comment: In your re-based solution, the re engine can do lookahead and backtracking to find the ':', but in pyparsing, the re in the Regex is not aware of the following Suppress(':') expression.  Try changing `path` to `Regex(r"[^:]+")`, which will consume everything except ':'s.

Comment: [Paul McGuire](http://stackoverflow.com/users/165216/paul-mcguire), actually the `path` can contain colons (`:`s), as in the example, where it is `foo:bar.txt`. So omitting colons from the `Regex` would not do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s="file://foo:bar.txt:r+"
path,flag=re.sub(r'.*\/\/(.*):(.*$)',r'\1,\2',s)
```